# Function change to arrow function

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
<input type="text" id="textbox_id" placeholder="Enter string here..." oninput="handleValueChange()">

<p id="result"></p>


function handleValueChange() {

    let y = document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;

    let x = document.getElementById('result');

    x.innerHTML = y;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go)

```js
<input type="text" id="textbox_id" placeholder="Enter string here..." oninput="handleValueChange()">

<p id="result"></p>


const handleValueChange = () => {

    let y = document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;

    let x = document.getElementById('result');

    x.innerHTML = y;
}
```